# HTML Как прижать буквы к краю страницы

Tags: html, css

Я убрал все padding и margin, но сами буквы по прежнему не достают до края страницы (см. скриншот) это такая особенность шрифта, либо это все таки можно настроить через CSS? Задача - сделать чтобы край букв упирался в край страницы без отступа.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
1234 And the text!
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотри информацию  по reset css.
Обрати внимание на reset от Eric Meyer

Comment: Это избавляет от некоторых проблем, но буквы все равно не доходят до края страницы. Использовал reset от Eric Meyer.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?